# API/SDK to create Server

Tags: c#, service, signalr

Hey I am trying to Build a service which can be a Web server or window server, This server will be running on the local system.

The client which will be running on the same network will be listening continuously for the data from server, or send data to the server if needed.

The issue is I don't know which is the best method, the system is complex where server has to handle all the clients and process the data every 900 millisecond and update the client with latest data, and it should be run on local network with MySQL server.

I have tried SingnelR with web server but i am not able to run the server locally (Means I am not able to connect with server using IP address).

Socket Programming is also one of the options, but it required lot of exception handling and Time consuming.

This server is like MQTT server where server will continuously Publish data and Subscribe to the Clients Topics.

Comment: What is the actual question here? This question is far too vague to get a proper answer.

Comment: How can I build Client and server service, where server will send data every second Also server has to listen data from Clients.

Comment: There isn't a single correct answer for this, and is WAY too broad to answer here.

Comment: So If I want to work with SignelR, Can I build a Signal R server using WPF? What I want is to run SignelR in the local system and Access the system using IP address? It's Hard to understand but i am totally new with this Server and client.

Comment: Is it possible to create SignalR service using c# and run using WPF application? I dont have idea and tried to find on online.